# How to test Firebase messaging refreshToken

Tags: firebase

I'm using FCM in my mobile app. The Firebase documentation state that the token can be refreshed (in rare cases). I'd like to test how the app behave once the token is refreshed, how can I invalidate the token and trigger a refresh?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually find out a way to test the refresh of the token: deleting the InstandeID: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId

> public void deleteInstanceId ()
>
> Resets Instance ID and revokes all tokens.